# .rspec file resetting every time system restarts - Rails / Guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

Every time I restart my system, my .rspec files in multiple projects gets reset to the following:

-fn --color

This stops all rspec tests running and is obviously frustrating as I have to manually edit this every time. It happens 100% of the time on system restarts, and sometimes while my system is still running.

My gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'bundler' # Allow bundler to work [Terry]

gem 'byebug', platform: :mri, groups: [:development, :test] # Rails default [Terry]

gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development # Rails default [Terry]
gem 'coveralls' # Code Coverage monitor [Terry]

gem 'decent_exposure' # @TODO Terry - gine?
gem 'devise' # User authentication [Terry @TODO Terry - Engine?

gem 'factory_girl' # Amazon S3 Image storage [Terry]
gem 'fog', '1.24.0' # Amazon S3 Image storage [Terry]
gem 'friendly_id' # Allow nice slugs in urls [Terry]

gem 'gretel', git: 'https://github.com/morsedigital/gretel.git' # Breadcrumb engine [Terry]
gem 'guard-rspec', groups: [:development, :test] # Allow guard for testing [Terry]
gem 'guard-rubocop', groups: [:development, :test] # Allow rubocop for guard for testing [Terry]

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5' # Rails default [Terry]

gem 'kaminari' # Pagination helper [Terry]

gem 'morse_active_record_helpers', groups: [:development, :test] # Allow morse helpers in models [Terry]
gem 'morse_spec_helpers', groups: [:development, :test] # Allow morse helpers in specs [Terry]
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5' # Rails default [Terry]

gem 'overcommit' # Applies rules around commits for niceness [Terry]

gem 'pry-byebug', groups:[:development, :test] # Pry r Ruby 2.2+ [Terry]
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0' # Rails default [Terry]

gem 'query_reviewer' # Make SQL optimisation easier [Terry]

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1' # Rails default [Terry]
gem 'rollbar' # Online exception monitoring [Terry]
gem 'rspec-rails', groups: [:development, :test] # RSpec testing framework [Terry]

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0' # Rails default [Terry]
gem 'simple_form' # Easy for builder [Terry]
gem 'spring', group: :development # Rails default [Terry]
gem 'spring-commands-rspec', groups: [:development, :test] #Allow guard and spring to play nicely [Terry]
gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0', group: :development # Rails default [Terry]

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5' # Rails default [Terry]
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby] # Rails default [Terry]

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' # Rails default [Terry]

gem 'web-console', group: :development # Rails default [Terry]
```

If anyone could provide any ideas as to why this might be happening you'll make me a happy bunny.

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: In case anyone else does what I did- was a line in my bash profile running on terminal startup.